# How to display images from SDcard to Gallery in Android emulator

Tags: android

i added image files to the Android Eclips DDMS platform.  after launching the emulator and clicking on the Gallery icon no image was displayed.  instead "No media was found" message was displayd.  any help to fix this.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try this......................

**1.** Open DDMS perspective.

**2.**

```
Goto FileExplorer option ---> Click on the arrow before the "mnt" folder ---> 
   Click on the arrow before the "sdcard" folder ---> Select the "DCIM" folder.
```

**3.** Then Goto the top right corner , and select the "Push a file onto device option".

**4.** Select the image to be pushed in.

**5.  RESTART THE EMULATOR....ELSE IT WILL NOT WORK....!!**

**6. AFTER RESTART, check your gallery..it will be there...**

Answer (score 2):

After pushing the files do this:

1. Goto the android menu, display the apps.
2. Then open Dev Tools and click Media Scanner. This will scan for the sdCard.